# Error 500 when updating my Google OAuth Client ID as owner

Tags: oauth, google-api

When creating a new Client ID for OAuth 2.0, I got a message "An error has occurred. Please retry later.". I tried several times this week without success. But I am user with the role owner and I created successfully a Client ID last month with the same user.

Besides, by checking the requests and responses sent with the Chrome Developer Tools, I can notice that I get a 500 error for `https://console.developers.google.com/m/project/my_project/client/web/create?xsrf=qwerty`

Is there something wrong at Google or it's me ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the problem is in the Request you are sending and the Response is an Error response. So if you want to identify the exact error, I suggest if you are passing credentials, double check it once; it might have changed or upgraded.

Comment: I am just using the HTML interface of the Google Developers Console.

Comment: Then if you are passing credentials, I suggest you to double check it once, it might have changed or upgraded.

Comment: I think your answer is irrelevant. It's not about coding. I configure my Client ID from my browser on Google Developers website.